# Изменение элемента в соответствии и элементом массива

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий массив:

```
var sizes = 
[
  {"id":"2","title":"16.0"},
  {"id":"3","title":"16.5"},
  {"id":"4","title":"17.0"}
]
```

Берется он при помощи json_encode в php. При рендеринге подставляю самое низкое значение из доступных в блок:

```
<div class="counter">
    <span class="counter__reduce">-</span>
    <span class="counter__count" data-id="<?=$sizes[0]['id']?>"><?=$sizes[0]['title']?></span>
    <span class="counter__increase">+</span>
</div>
```

При клике на `.counter__reduce` и `.counter__increase` мне необходимо брать следующий элемент из массива, т.е. если сейчас `$('.counter__count').text()` равен 16.0, то мне нужно брать элемент с id 3, 16.5.

Каким образом это лучше всего сделать? Т.е. фильтр должен происходить каждый раз после нажатия на кнопку + или -.

Еще вопрос, уже строго по арифметическим функциям js. Есть незамысловатый код:

```
$('.counter .counter__reduce').click(function(e){
    var counter = $('.counter .counter__count');
    var count = parseFloat(counter.text()).toFixed(1);
    console.log(count);
    counter.text(count - 0.5);
});
```

Но при нескольких нажатиях на кнопку, я получаю в консоли следующее:

- 16.0
- 15.5
- 1515.0
- 1514.5
- 15141514.0
- 15141513.5
- 1514151315141513.0
- 1514151315141512.5

С чем это связано? И как мне решить эту задачу в целом?

Answer (score 0):

Задайте, пожалуйста, первую половину Вашего вопроса как отдельный вопрос.

Вторая половина, конечно, интереснее.

Ожидаемое поведение:

```js
$('.reduce').click(function(e) {
  var counter = $('.count');
  var count = parseFloat(counter.text()).toFixed(1);
  console.log(count);
  counter.text(count - 0.5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">16</div>
<button class="reduce">Reduce</button>
```

А вот что у Вас:

```js
$('.reduce').click(function(e) {
  var counter = $('.count');
  var count = parseFloat(counter.text()).toFixed(1);
  console.log(count);
  counter.text(count - 0.5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">16</div>
<div class="count"></div>
<button class="reduce">Reduce</button>
```

Найдите отличие ).

---

Вот решение:

```
var counter = $(this).closest('.counter').find('.counter__count');
```